# Datetime field overflow if date > '9999-12-31 23:59:59.4'

Tags: mysql, datetime

For my table `admin_tool_functionality`

```
CREATE TABLE admin_tool_functionality (

    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    admin_tool_functionality_type_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__admin_tool_functionality__admin_tool_functionality_type
        FOREIGN KEY (admin_tool_functionality_type_id)
        REFERENCES admin_tool_functionality_type(id),

    PRIMARY KEY (id, admin_tool_functionality_type_id),

    price FLOAT NOT NULL,

    valid_from_day DATETIME NOT NULL, 

    valid_until_day DATETIME NOT NULL,

    CHECK(valid_from_day < valid_until_day)

);
```

This insertion works fine:

```
INSERT INTO admin_tool_functionality 
    (admin_tool_functionality_type_id, price, valid_from_day, valid_until_day)
VALUES
    (1, 13.37, '2016-01-01', '9999-12-31 23:59:59.4');
```

But any value lager than `'9999-12-31 23:59:59.4'` is failing:

```
INSERT INTO admin_tool_functionality 
    (admin_tool_functionality_type_id, price, valid_from_day, valid_until_day)
VALUES
    (1, 13.37, '2016-01-01', '9999-12-31 23:59:59.5');
```

Giving me:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Datetime function: datetime field overflow
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
```

despite the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) saying

> the range for `DATETIME` values is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000'` to `'9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'`

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Timezones, perhaps? This seems like an odd edge case to care about...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [fractional seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) documentation for MySQL and note @Pieter comments regarding MySQL version.

Before MySQL 5.6.4 the microseconds are discarded and not stored but can be used in the following situations as per the documentation:

> A trailing fractional part is permissible in contexts such as literal values, and in the arguments to or return values from some temporal functions.

On or after MySQL 5.6.4, fractional seconds support was expanded.

Unless you define fractional seconds (*fsp*) for your `DATETIME` column, it will default to 0 i.e. no microseconds.

Based on this comment in the documentation:

> Inserting a TIME, DATE, or TIMESTAMP value with a fractional seconds part into a column of the same type but having fewer fractional digits results in rounding

An assumption and theory based on the above comment and your failing `INSERT` is that .4 or even .499999 (up to 6 fractional digits which MySQL 5.6.4 or newer supports) will round *down*, whereas .5 or greater will round *up*.

Since microseconds are considered *fractional*, that would make the seconds the *integer* or whole part of the number. If 59.5 were to round up, that would result in your date part having to change (move forward 1 day) because time part range is `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`. This behaviour could be considered unexpected outside of a function that adjusts dates and times.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense now. I'm using 5.6.24 at the moment! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Fractional seconds support has been added for `TIME`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` since MySQL 5.6.4. Before that version, you are not allowed to add fractional seconds to timestamps (see [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)).

Are you by any chance using a MySQL version before 5.6.4?