# What is the exact maximum value for TIMESTAMP in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) states that -

> the range for TIMESTAMP values is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'

But when I get this when I try to enter the maximum value:

```
mysql> insert into integration_table (`TIMESTAMP`) VALUES ('2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999' for column 'TIMESTAMP' at row 1
```

If I incrementally decrease the value, the maximum value that will work is `'2038-01-19 03:14:07.499999'`

- MySQL version is `mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)` (running in Docker)
- Column definition is `` `TIMESTAMP` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, ``
- Table definition is `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`

I know that MySQL supports microseconds since version 5.6.4, so that's not the issue.

Am I misunderstanding something or is this some configuration issue?

Thanks

Comment: Just noticed I get the same behaviour with DATETIME - for .999999 I get "datetime field overflow" and it works up to .499999

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime field overflow if date > '9999-12-31 23:59:59.4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553754/datetime-field-overflow-if-date-9999-12-31-235959-4)

Comment: That question was about MySQL version, which wasn't my problem, but it led me to the answer - Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining the column as `TIMESTAMP` means it does not support microseconds, so .5 and above will be rounded up, which makes this value out of range.

The column needs to be defined as `TIMESTAMP(6)` to support 6 digit microseconds.